# SQLAlchemy OperationalError no such table

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a Flask app, and I have a page with a form to register new users. But when I type some data, I get the error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: user`. In the file config.py I have this line
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///example.sqlite"` and this is the rest of my code:

**flask_start.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_utils import page_bp
from db_creation import db


def create_app():
    appname = "IOT - PROJECT NASTIS"
    app = Flask(appname)
    myconfig = Config
    app.config.from_object(myconfig)
    app.register_blueprint(page_bp, url_prefix='')
    db.init_app(app)
    return app


def setup_database(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    if not os.path.isfile('/tmp/test.sqlite'):
        setup_database(app)
    port = 8000
    interface = '0.0.0.0'
    app.run(host=interface, port=port, debug=True)
```

**db_creation.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**flask_utils.py**

```
db_creation import db
from User import User

page_bp = Blueprint("page_bp", __name__)

@page_bp.route('/mainPage/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user = User(form.username.data, form.email.data,
                    sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data)))
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Thanks for registering, you can now log in!!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('page_bp.register'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

**User.py**

```
from db_creation import db


class User(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure out what is the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `db.create_all()` it needs to know which tables to create-- it can tell that by which models it currently can see.

`User` isn't imported in your `start_flask.py` file-- so when `db.create_all()` is run it pretty much goes 'huh, I'm not aware of any models, I guess I'll just create an empty database with no tables' it doesn't know to go and look in other files, so you just need to introduce them :)

Adding `from User import User` to the imports in the `start_flask.py` file should solve that.

Also-- you're checking for a file in `/tmp/...` to trigger your 'no database file yet' check, but your `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` isn't matching that.

Comment: If I import User I get `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'user' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.` ...what does that mean?

Comment: You're quite right! I missed that `User` gets seem when the `flask_utils` is imported.  The code otherwise looks alright. Just ran a simplified version ( https://gist.github.com/doobeh/ee0b8b95fbc9539d7695a9788089e9ee ) and db was created.

Comment: Looks like the problem was a typo in import statement! The lesson lo learn here is: never code when you are hungry